# Adding  Image to UIActionSheet UIButton and App Approval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet, appstore-approval

I want to submit an iPhone application, and I am concerned about the following line of code which add an Image to the UIActionSheet Button:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button"];

[[[action valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

does that compromise any of apple app sumbition rules? is it legal? please tell me if so.

Thanks.

Comment: I have same question did you submit you app with this code ?

Comment: actually yes i have submitted the app and it got approved with the same code above, but it cant be guaranteed as @gcamp said **play safe and don't use it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* legal, since `_buttons`is not a public API.

(I would say however that it would pass Apple's review since you are using KVC and they have no way to know that this is a private call. Still, play safe and don't use it!)

Comment: Key value coding : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/ (i.e. the fact that you use `valueForKey`)